# How to set SETA to not abort on keypress?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

In contrast to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8676/how-to-stop-breaking-seta-in-x3-terran-conflict) I simply want to be able to e.g. open the sector map via <kbd>.</kbd>. However, pressing any key results in killing SETA. In contrast, using the mouse I *can* open the map without stopping SETA, but using shortcuts is more comfortable of course, so can this behaviour be changed?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can open the map first, and then press the <kbd>J</kbd> key to initiate SETA.

Comment: yes, I think that works. But what I'd like to do is sightseeing while I'm flying in SETA and only every now and then check the map for my location (or trading prices of a station currently passed by while travelling to another one) without aborting SETA. But still thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yeah unless someone has written a mod, any key press or joystick input is going to shut SETA off as far as I am aware.